# Symfony flush in preUpdate Doctrine Listener

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

Hi I have an prePersist and preUpdate listener:

```
<?php

namespace FM\AppBundle\EventListener;

use Doctrine\ORM\Event\LifecycleEventArgs;
use FM\AdminBundle\Entity\Address\DeliveryAddress;

class DeliveryAddressListener
{

    /**
     * @param LifecycleEventArgs $args
     */
    public function prePersist(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
    {
        $entity = $args->getEntity();

        if(!$entity instanceof DeliveryAddress){
            return;
        }

        $this->addNameToUser($args);
        $this->addPostalToUser($args);
    }

    /**
     * @param LifecycleEventArgs $args
     */
    public function preUpdate(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
    {
        $entity = $args->getEntity();

        if(!$entity instanceof DeliveryAddress){
            return;
        }

        $this->addPostalToUser($args);
    }

    /**
     * @param LifecycleEventArgs $args
     */
    public function addNameToUser(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
    {
        /** @var DeliveryAddress $deliveryAdress */
        $deliveryAdress = $args->getEntity();
        $user = $deliveryAdress->getOwner();

        if(empty($user->getFirstName())) $user->setFirstName($deliveryAdress->getFirstName());
        if(empty($user->getLastName())) $user->setLastName($deliveryAdress->getLastName());
    }

    /**
     * @param LifecycleEventArgs $args
     */
    public function addPostalToUser(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
    {
        /** @var DeliveryAddress $deliveryAdress */
        $deliveryAdress = $args->getEntity();
        $user = $deliveryAdress->getOwner();
        $user->setPostalCode($deliveryAdress->getZipCode());
    }
}
```

service.yml:

```
delivery_address.listener:
    class: FM\AppBundle\EventListener\DeliveryAddressListener
    tags:
        - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: prePersist }
        - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: preUpdate }
```

The prePersist works fine. But the preUpdate does not persist anything.

And when I add this code bellow in my **addPostalToUser()** function, my nginx server crash :

```
$args->getEntityManager()->persist($deliveryAdress);
$args->getEntityManager()->flush();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is that changes to associations of the updated entity are not allowed in this event. So changing the user association on DeliveryAddress will not work.

[See documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/events.html#preupdate)

You can do this using an [onFlush listener](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/events.html#onflush) - it's a little more work, but will do what you're after.

Comment: Ok thanks. I'm trying to do it with a onFlush, but it does not seem to work either. A post a new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37831828/symfony-onflush-doctrine-listener