# Symfony onFlush Doctrine Listener

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

Hi I have an onFlush listener:

```
<?php

namespace FM\AppBundle\EventListener;

use FM\AdminBundle\Entity\Address\DeliveryAddress;
use Doctrine\ORM\Event\OnFlushEventArgs;

class DeliveryAddressListener
{
    /**
     * @param OnFlushEventArgs $args
     */
    public function onFlush(OnFlushEventArgs $args)
    {
        $em = $args->getEntityManager();
        $uow = $em->getUnitOfWork();

        foreach ($uow->getScheduledEntityUpdates() as $entity) {
            if ($entity instanceof DeliveryAddress) {
                $this->addPostalToUser($entity, $args);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param DeliveryAddress  $deliveryAddress
     * @param OnFlushEventArgs $args
     */
    public function addPostalToUser(DeliveryAddress $deliveryAddress, OnFlushEventArgs $args)
    {
        $em = $args->getEntityManager();
        $user = $deliveryAddress->getOwner();

        $user->setPostalCode($deliveryAddress->getZipCode());
    }
}
```

service.yml:

```
delivery_address.listener:
    class: FM\AppBundle\EventListener\DeliveryAddressListener
    tags:
        - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: onFlush }
```

I'm  trying to set the new zipCode to the User. But it does not seem to work.

Even when I'm adding a `$em->persist($user)`.

I'm looking throught this doc: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/events.html#onflush

But I don't understand how I can make it works with this explanation:

`If you create and persist a new entity in onFlush, then calling EntityManager#persist() is not enough. You have to execute an additional call to $unitOfWork->computeChangeSet($classMetadata, $entity).`

Answer (score 6):

When manipulating fields, they should be done in the preUpdaet/prePersist.

**AppBundle/EventSubscriber/EntitySubscriber.php**

```
namespace AppBundle\EventSubscriber;

use Doctrine\Common\EventSubscriber;
use Doctrine\ORM\Event\LifecycleEventArgs;
use Doctrine\ORM\Event\OnFlushEventArgs;

class EntitySubscriber implements EventSubscriber
{
    private $now;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->now = \DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d h:i:s', date('Y-m-d h:i:s'));
    }

    public function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return [
            'prePersist',
            'preUpdate'
        ];
    }

    public function prePersist(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
    {
        $entity        = $args->getEntity();
        $entityManager = $args->getEntityManager();

        if (method_exists($entity, 'setCreatedAt')) {
            $entity->setUpdatedAt($this->now);
        }

        if (method_exists($entity, 'setUpdatedAt')) {
            $entity->setUpdatedAt($this->now);
        }
    }

    public function preUpdate(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
    {
        $entity        = $args->getEntity();
        $entityManager = $args->getEntityManager();

        if (method_exists($entity, 'setUpdatedAt')) {
            $entity->setUpdatedAt($this->now);
        }
    }
}
```

**services.yml**

```
    app.entity_subscriber:
        class: AppBundle\EventSubscriber\EntitySubscriber
        tags:
            - { name: doctrine.event_subscriber, connection: default }
```

Answer (score 5):

If you need to **create an object, persist it and flush it** in your listener, then tlorens' answer won't work, as Doctrine docs mention that this must be done with an onFlush Event.

Initial question was how to make it work following docs advice:
`If you create and persist a new entity in onFlush, then calling EntityManager#persist() is not enough. You have to execute an additional call to $unitOfWork->computeChangeSet($classMetadata, $entity).`

And this is a way to achieve this:

```
/**
 * @param OnFlushEventArgs $eventArgs
 */
public function onFlush(OnFlushEventArgs  $eventArgs)
{
    $em = $eventArgs->getEntityManager();
    $uow = $em->getUnitOfWork();

    foreach ($uow->getScheduledEntityUpdates() as $entity) {
        if ($entity instanceof User) {
            $uow->computeChangeSets();
            $changeSet = $uow->getEntityChangeSet($entity);
            // In this exemple, User has a boolean property 'enabled' and a log will be created if it is passed to 'false'
            if ($changeSet && isset($changeSet['enabled']) && $changeSet['enabled'][1] === false) {
                $log = new Log();
                $em->persist($log);
                $uow->computeChangeSet($em->getClassMetadata(get_class($log)), $log);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: There's components that use my solution exact same logic. My answer was to correctly place the object manipulation in the right event.  Not sure why you'd go through the complexities of doing this in onFlush when it can be done perfectly well elsewhere.

Answer (score -1):

Well it works when I use that:

```
// Remove event, if we call $this->em->flush() now there is no infinite recursion loop!
$eventManager->removeEventListener('onFlush', $this);
```

My Listener

```
namespace FM\AppBundle\EventListener;

use FM\AdminBundle\Entity\Address\DeliveryAddress;
use Doctrine\ORM\Event\OnFlushEventArgs;

class DeliveryAddressListener
{
    /**
     * @param OnFlushEventArgs $args
     */
    public function onFlush(OnFlushEventArgs $args)
    {
        $em = $args->getEntityManager();
        $uow = $em->getUnitOfWork();
        $eventManager = $em->getEventManager();

        // Remove event, if we call $this->em->flush() now there is no infinite recursion loop!
        $eventManager->removeEventListener('onFlush', $this);

        foreach ($uow->getScheduledEntityUpdates() as $entity) {
            if ($entity instanceof DeliveryAddress) {
                $this->addPostalToUser($entity, $args);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param DeliveryAddress  $deliveryAddress
     * @param OnFlushEventArgs $args
     */
    public function addPostalToUser(DeliveryAddress $deliveryAddress, OnFlushEventArgs $args)
    {
        $em = $args->getEntityManager();
        $user = $deliveryAddress->getOwner();

        $user->setPostalCode($deliveryAddress->getZipCode());
        $em->flush();
    }
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't flush. You should be instead calling recompute using the UOW functions. See an example here in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34342324/doctrine-eventlistener-onflush-does-not-save-original-entity/34342751#34342751 - problem is your flush calls a flush, which calls the listener, etc

Comment: Even if I use that? `$eventManager->removeEventListener('onFlush', $this);
`